# RESTful API callback for stand alone applications

Tags: rest, desktop-application

I want to use a RESTful API of a web service that I have. However, I really don't know how the web service knows how to "give it" to the stand alone application since it does not have an URL. Is there a mechanism that makes URLs in this case not needed?

Comment: do you want call the client from the rest web service?

Comment: No, I want to call the REST web service from the stand alone client.

Comment: But how is the web service supposed to know where to send the result of the HTTP message that was sent to it?

Comment: The stand alone application know the url right? So it can call the ws. The ws will return the response automatically to the caller who send the request. http://wiki.hashphp.org/images/6/67/HTTP_Model.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read up a little more on what REST is and does. By its nature REST is a mechanism for requesting data. I.e. it is a "pull" not a "push". REST is typically used over Http - hence the need for a Url, In the same way you request/pull data everytime you visit a webpage.

If you wish to notify from one system to another as soon as change happen then you need to look at something other than REST. Alternatively your client can poll the REST service continually to check its response.

Comment: OK, that was my mistake. When I have a stand alone application the REST service does not need to know where to send he data, because the stand alone application pulls it from the service. My problem has a bit more to do with CAS as you can see in my last question on SO. CAS requires an service URL, that is my problem.

Comment: Okay, it sounds to me then that you need to build your own REST service for CAS to call back to? So you tell CAS your Url and CAS will send you data to the url you have provided.

Comment: No, thats what I thought before. The point is that CAS want to send me a service specific ticket that I need for autorisation of my stand alone app. That means that CAS must know which application asks for the ticket since it is service specific. However, stand alone applications don't have an URL which makes me wonder how I can tell CAS that a stand alone app asked for its ticket.

Comment: The examples for the RESTful API of CAS show that you can and should give the service URL, thats the problem

Comment: I think this is probably the wrong question for what you're now asking - the other one you mentioned is more to the crux of the matter. I will say, though, that I was under the impression that CAS was used for web single sign-on. Therefore it will naturally request a URL as its used for the web. I do not think you will be able to get around your problem without providing an endpoint/url to be called back. So either do that, or move away from CAS